# Could not construct original matrix using SVD

Tags: matlab, stft, spectrogram, svd

I need to

- read a `.wav` file
- make a 2D matrix from it using the STFT
- generate its singular value decomposition
- do some watermarking

but I can't build the original matrix again via matrix multiplication:

```
 x = audioread('0.wav');
 stft = spectrogram(x); 
 [U,S,V] = svd(stft);
 stftb=U*S*V.';
```

The problem is that STFT and STFTb are not the same.

Comment: What do you get when you type `max(max(abs(stftb-stft)))`?

Comment: @MattL.ans =   76.2564

Comment: OK, since your matrices are complex-valued schvaba986's answer is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to comment but you need to use the conjugate transpose in your formula for the result to be correct. So try `stftb=U*S*V';` in the last line of code. Note that I removed the `.` which makes a difference since the matrices you are working with are complex.

Comment: Why are they complex? `stft` is real-valued, isn't it?

Comment: I think that MATLAB divides the signal in 8 segments and returns a complex value when you call the `spectrogram` function like that.

Comment: I guess you're right, `spectrogram` actually computes the short-time Fourier transform, not the spectrogram (which would be real-valued because it's a squared magnitude).

Comment: Oh, now I understand your comment... You can use multiple outputs to get a PSD among other values but like this it's only the STFT

Comment: @schvaba986 thanks, you're right. Note that now the result of max(max(abs(stftb-sftt))) is 7.6810e-14